# List 1 row and not all rows in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason this is returning everything from the member_details table when all i want is to return a single row that equals to the selected item in the drop down list.

**Here is the php for it: i thought it would return the row which equaled the value of the drop down but its just listing it all.**

```
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['members'])) {
        $ResultSet = getTableResults("member_details");
        echo "<h1> Member Details </h1>";
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='6'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>Id</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Job</th> <th>Wage</th> <th>Hobby</th> ";

        foreach ($ResultSet as $row) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row ['member_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row ['second_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['job'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['wage'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['hobby'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "<table>";
    }
    ?>
```

**If you want to see more code to make more sense of it please ask and il edit and update the question.**

```
 function getTableResults() {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT member_details.member_id, members.first_name,      members.second_name, member_details.wage, member_details.job, member_details.hobby
       FROM members
       INNER JOIN member_details
       ON members.member_id=member_details.member_id";
    $mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

    $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
    return $ResultSet;
  }
```

Comment: yeah, we'll need to see the `getTableResults()` code

Comment: 'getTableResults' is the only database related code in there. What framework or library is this?

Comment: I am using netbeans for php and using wamp and phpmyadmin

Comment: Your SQL clause doesn't have a WHERE clause, so it's returning everything. You'll want to pass in the ID of the row you want to select as a parameter to the function.

Comment: @andrewsi so like WHERE member_id = member_id or WHERE members.member_id = member_details.member_id ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have any Condition while requesting your information, `getTableResults()` fetches all Data that is stored to your table. You need to change that function and add a `WHERE xy` condition. Probably something like this:

```
 function getTableResults( $id ) {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT member_details.member_id, members.first_name,members.second_name, member_details.wage, member_details.job, member_details.hobby
       FROM members
       INNER JOIN member_details
       ON members.member_id=member_details.member_id WHERE member_details.member_id = '$id'";
    $mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

    $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
    return $ResultSet;
  }
```

Then Call the function with the requred member-id as parameter.
Anyway, I'd recommend you to inform yourself about prepared statements to prevent SQL-Injection here!

Comment: Do you mean stored procedures, or prepared statements?

Comment: Where would i link the id to though in my POST

Comment: @andrewsi prepared statements of course. Mixed that one up :)
@Bob Marks That i can't tell you. Check your form, and the value your `Select` does give you. How do you identify the User you want to get the information from?

Comment: @T3H40 I am confused, its only viewing id and name. Very confused, it is something to do with the form i know but i am unsure

Comment: @BobMarks Try the following: `print_r( $_POST);` - this will show you all Information the form sends to you. Search for the User-ID you need and you will find your required parameter.

Comment: :) Cool stuff! Glad I could help. Happy Coding!